# I have problems with HTMl table, It needs to be solved without using CSS

Tags: html, html-table

I wrote this structure for table in the image, but it doesn't work. What is wrong with that and why `rowspan` and `colspan` do not work? I've used CSS only for setting width and height of cells.

[image]

```css
td {
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <caption>Another table 1.0</caption>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">r1c1</td>
        <td>r1c3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">r1c4</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">r1c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">r2c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">r3c1</td>
        <td colspan="2">r3c4</td>
        <td>r3c6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r4c1</td>
        <td colspan="2">r4c2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">r4c4</td>
        <td colspan="2">r4c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">r5c1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">r5c3</td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">r5c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r6c4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but I think part of it is that at the beginning of rendering the table, the browser can't tell how many rows and columns you want total. If you put a dummy `<tr></tr>` at the beginning of your code with six empty `<td></td>` in it, it renders closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without CSS you need to explicitly set the size of cells.

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <caption>HTML only</caption>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" width="120" height="60">r1c1</td>
        <td width="60" height="30">r1c3</td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="60" height="60">r1c4</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" width="120" height="60">r1c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" width="60" height="60">r2c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" width="120" height="30">r3c1</td>
        <td colspan="2" width="120" height="30">r3c4</td>
        <td width="60" height="30">r3c6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="60" height="30">r4c1</td>
        <td colspan="2" width="120" height="30">r4c2</td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="60" height="60">r4c4</td>
        <td colspan="2" width="120" height="30">r4c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" width="120" height="60">r5c1</td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="60" height="60">r5c3</td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" width="120" height="60">r5c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="60" height="30">r6c4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you can have minimal CSS, you need to add 6 `<col>` tags and set its width and set height on `tr`.

```css
col {
  width: 60px;
}
tr {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
    <caption>With CSS</caption>
    <col><col><col><col><col><col>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">r1c1</td>
        <td>r1c3</td>
        <td rowspan="2">r1c4</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">r1c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">r2c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">r3c1</td>
        <td colspan="2">r3c4</td>
        <td>r3c6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r4c1</td>
        <td colspan="2">r4c2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">r4c4</td>
        <td colspan="2">r4c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">r5c1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">r5c3</td>
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">r5c5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r6c4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        td {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        } 
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">r1c1</td>
            <td>r1c3</td>
            <td>r1c4</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">r1c5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">r2c3</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">r3c1</td>
            <td colspan="2">r3c4</td>
            <td>r3c6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>r4c1</td>
            <td colspan="2">r4c2</td>
            <td rowspan="2">r4c4</td>
            <td colspan="2">r4c5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">r5c1</td>
            <td rowspan="2">r5c3</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">r5c5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>r6c4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check what? That this doesn't work either?